# Laravel Nested Set Data For User Table

Tags: laravel

It is okay if use nested set data on User table in Laravel? Every time new user register, it will run insert process. As said here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

> Nested sets are very slow for inserts because it requires updating left and right domain values for all records in the table after the insert. This can cause a lot of database thrash[citation needed] as many rows are rewritten and indexes rebuilt.

So, the insert process when new user register would be slow, right? Because it will update left and right position column every time insert new user record.

Anyone have suggestion? Is it okay to use Nested Set Model on User table?

By the way, this is some package that I've looked.

1. https://github.com/etrepat/baum (currently used)
2. https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset
3. https://github.com/franzose/ClosureTable

I think Closure Table is okay for this, but I want to hear suggestions from others. Thanks. :)

Comment: Why do you need/want nested set for users?

Comment: @Skysplit I want assign child to user. So, in User table, it would have parent_id column, I want to fetch parent and also children user details.

Comment: I am using this package `https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list`, seems pretty much performant and easy to use, no need extra db fields other than the `parent_id`, since you don't specify why the need of nested data all I can do is suggest a package :)